# How to use Rich Text editor for an XUL application

Tags: tinymce, xul, fckeditor, richtext, richtextctrl

I am trying  to implement Rich text editor like http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/ 
for my XUL application. It looks like i can't user tinymce as some of its scripts is using the element "document.body" and firefox is not supporting it. Did any implement a rich text editor in XUL. Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that firefox doesn't support document.body. `document` is different depending on what kind of document you have. In HTML you have `document.body` because an HTML document will always have a `<BODY>` element. XUL doesn't have a `<BODY>` so it's natural that the document doesn't have a `document.body` property.

The problem is that TinyMCE is heavily depending on that the document is HTML. I don't know the code for TinyMCE but I would suspect that it can be modified to support XUL as well.

Answer (score 2):

An HTML `<frame>` with TinyMCE is the easiest way to go about it. The harder but possibly better way would be to include a `<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>` tag in the document and assign document.body to that element.

Comment: Grey, I will try this and keep you posted. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `<html:iframe src="URL to your editor">` is the easiest way to do it